# Riley Riddle - Fork, Mountain, London, Cancer

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix, is not very good
>   My infix, a bird not in wood
>   My suffix, might be the answer
>   Fork, Mountain, London, Cancer

Comment: I couldn't figure out the answer, but you've inspired me to post [another riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/80965/5373) :-)

Comment: @RandAlThor I'm glad to hear that :)

Comment: @Randal'Thor, I have to admit that the answer to the riddle that you were inspired to create helped me figure out the answer to this one. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, @Randal'Thor. I was referring to the answer you only recently marked as incorrect :-)

Comment: @Domosed Although *now* mine has been correctly solved, so I'll delete my previous comment.

Comment: Novice puzzler here!  What is the significance of the last line "Fork, Mountain, London, Cancer"?   It that just a distraction, or does it define an aspect of the answer?

Comment: @PetervdL it's a bit of both in this case ;) but it definitely defines and aspect of the answer. You could say that it's a usage or example of the word. So in this riddle format, the first line is the first part of the word, the 2nd line is the middle part of the word, and the 3rd line is the last part of the word. The 4th line represents the word as a whole. Usually containing some sort of wordplay, reference, synonym, or example of the word. In the case of this riddle, I had a lot of fun with it and made it  a reference/example of the word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could it be

> malarkey? This word means "meaningless talk; nonsense".
>
>  mal is a prefix for "in a faulty manner" like malfunction
>  lark is a bird
>  key is one of the synonyms to "answer"
>  "Fork, Mountain, London, Cancer" is kind of malarkey :-)

Comment: Also, I believe the bird you suggested is usually found in open fields rather than woods.

Comment: That's correct :] as a prefix, that word means bad, and that type of bird nests in the ground. Well done!

Comment: Can you edit it your answer to include the meaning of the word? So that way people who are unfamiliar with that term can understand is ^-^

Comment: Sure, I have just updated the answer to include the meaning of the word. Thanks.