# I may also be found in your body

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

My infix won't tell you a thing,
But you can find me from the rest:
My suffix sounds exactly like me,
And my prefix is already half known.

In wood or wire, what am I?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are a:

> Knot

My infix won't tell you a thing,

> "no"

My suffix sounds exactly like me,

> "not" is pronounced just like "knot"

And my prefix is already half known.

> "kno" is half of "known"

In wood or wire, what am I?

> Knots in wood, and knots in wire are both very common.

I may also be found in your body.

> You can also have a knot in a muscle.

Comment: I was thinking of the singular form (without the final S), but yes, you got it. Nicely done!

Answer (score 11):

The answer is

> Knee

Explanation

> you can find it in your body. The suffix is nee and sounds like the word knee. the prefix is "kn" which is the first half of "known". The infix is ne which is no in some language as far as I remember.

Comment: How does wood and wire fit in?

Comment: @hexomino, I don't know about wire, but according to wikipedia rot13(Va jbbqjbexvat, n xarr vf n angheny be phg, pheirq cvrpr bs jbbq).

Comment: Nope, sorry, this isn't it. However, you're thinking along the right lines with two of the three (prefix/infix/suffix) parts. When you find the answer, it should fit better with all the clues.